# Convert Scalar to Mat in JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Using JavaCV I'm trying to apply different colors to areas which are between two numbers in an input range. See the following code for an example of how it should work:

```
Mat mask = new Mat();
inRange(intensity, new Scalar(0.0), new Scalar(0.3), mask);
image.setTo(new Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), mask);
```

I can't compile that code though since JavaCV seems to expect a `Mat` instead of `Scalar` object in both inRange and setTo, see definition here:

```
@Namespace("cv") public static native void inRange(@ByVal Mat src,
       @ByVal Mat lowerb, @ByVal Mat upperb, @ByVal Mat dst);
```

In the OpenCV documentation `Scalar` should be ok instead of `Mat`. Is there a way to just convert `Scalar` to `Mat` so this works?

I've noticed that I can use `cvInRangeS` instead of `inRange` but I haven't been able to find an equivalent to the `setTo` function.

Answer (score 0):

The error you should be getting when calling `inRange` with a malformed `Mat` is `OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The lower bounary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar)`, or something along those lines (note the misspelling).

If you want to use the `Mat` as a `Scalar`, you can initialize the `Mat` with a `double[]` or `Scalar` object. For example: `new Mat(new double[]{255, 255, 255, 0})`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the JavaCV api, but I was having the same issue and found this out through trial and error.